# Sum Type Vs Record of Maybes

Tags: haskell

A problem I'm facing often when designing data type in Haskell, is to either use sum type or records of Maybe Eithers.

A simple example would be to modelize FX operation, spot or a forward, where the only difference is the presence or not of a "maturity" date (  One way would be using a sum type an explicitely specify if it's a spot or a forward.

```
data Amount = Amount { amount :: Double, currency :: String }
data Fx = Spot { tranDate :: Day, soldAmount :: Amount, boughtAmount :: Amount }
        | Forward  { tranDate :: Day, paidAmount :: Amount, boughtAmount :: Amount , maturity :: Day}
```

Another way would be to just have the `maturity` as a `Maybe'

```
data Fx = Fx { tranDate :: Day
             , soldAmount :: Amount
             , boughtAmount :: Amount
             , maturity (Maybe Day)
             }
```

Or anything else

Comment: I'm not sure what domain you're talking about here.  If `Spot` and `Forward` are quite distinct behaviors that require the same data, I'd go with the `Spot | Forward` ADT; if they are very similar and one just adds a little bit of information / complexity, I'd go with the `Maybe Day` solution.

Answer (score 5):

I don't recommend working with sum types that have named fields. They are unsafe for accessors that only exist on one of the branches. And they aren't very DRY if you have repeated fields.

But instead of putting the `Maybe` inside of a record, I would define a wrapping record, like this:

```
data Spot = Spot 
    { tranDate :: Day
    , soldAmount :: Amount
    , boughtAmount :: Amount 
    }

data Forward = Forward
    { spot :: Spot
    , maturity :: Day
    }
```

And perhaps even a `HasSpot` typeclass as well, that both `Spot` and `Forward` would implement.

But now it is difficult to put Spot and Forward values in the same collection. Perhaps one could use a type like `(Maybe Day, Spot)` in that case.

The "wrap it" approach of this answer doesn't generalize very well to more than one optional field, however.

Answer (score 1):

The second example doesn't communicate well.  You have to check `maturity` to distinguish forwards and spot.  The sum type communicates much better.

Comment: The sum type is less readable IMHO, because of the duplicate fields.

Comment: I think your answer combines the best of both.